# Rotate image frame via office.js

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I want to rotate the image as well as imageFrame in Word.

I am creating the Word Add-in which rotates the image and insert into the document using `office.js`. I successfully insert the rotated image in document but the image frame is not rotated.

Can anyone help me with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.